# Adaboost model crashes RAM

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, adaboost

Trained an Adaboost Regressor with following parameters :

```
base_estimator= DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 5)
n_estimators=500
learning_rate= 0.3
random_state = 100
```

The dataset I am using has 24 features with around 2 million samples. Each feature is an integer.
After the completing the model training on 80% of the data when trying to use the predict and score functions. The function kills the RAM rapidly and system crashed. 
What might have been the reason behind this?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
model = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=500, base_estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 5), learning_rate=0.3, loss='square')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.predict(X_test)# This line crashes the RAM very rapidly.
```

Comment: How much memory do you have, anyway? Can you show us some code?

Comment: For the next time, pls spend a minute to see how to actually format your code snippets (done it for you now).

Comment: @AKX I have updated the code snippet.

Comment: @TheMatoder Great, now please also let us know how exactly your system crashes. Do you get a MemoryError? Does everything just hang? And, again, how much memory do you have? 500 estimators is a lot.

Comment: I am using Goolge Colab. Do you want me to share the log? @AKX

Comment: Honestly, just try with less estimators than 500.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll try to do that.

Comment: It seems very strange that prediction should break if fitting proceeded without issue...